# How do I track down the place in my swift code where I'm unwrapping an optional unsafely?

Tags: xcode, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

The code arked where the failure occurs comes straight from Apple's Lister sample code:

```
var window: UIWindow!
```

...

```
var splitViewController: UISplitViewController {

    return window.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
    }
```

When I try to run the code, it gives me the error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".  by using breakpoints, I can tell that wind is still nil at the point this first runs, but that's not a problem for the straight up sample project.
Since it executes in the sample code, it seems like I've got something fouled up in one of the  splitview's subviews. Am I thinking about that right, and if so, is there a good way in the debugger to find what's going on, or which optional is my problem?

Comment: Have you tried breaking on exceptions?

Comment: Yes, it still fails in the same place, same way.

Comment: No, I mean breaking on exceptions to find the location where the error occurs!

Comment: Yes, I have an exception breakpoint turned on.

Comment: The debugger should already be stopping on the error. If `window` is nil, then it's an error to use it, that's just how implicitly unwrapped optionals work. Why don't you just check it first, or make sure this code doesn't run until after the window is configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit: I've just seen the age of this question, but maybe some else will find it useful]

It's just a guess, but you should check the interface builder connection between the window and your outlet. And you have to check whether you access this function BEFORE windowDidLoad was called.

The failure is, as stated by @jtbandes, the desired behaviors for implicitly unwrapped optionals when they're nil.
So you have to check window for nil, for example by doing the following:

```
var splitViewController: UISplitViewController {
  return window?.rootViewController as UISplitViewController
}
```

I don't know in the moment what will happen if this function return nil. I guess you have to declare it to return an optional UISplitViewController to silence the compiler.